# Angular ContentChild from template

Tags: angular

I have a wrapper component for an input (which is more complex than this):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tw-input-multi',
  templateUrl: './input-multi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-multi.component.scss'],
  host:{
    'class': 'field'
  }
})
export class InputMultiComponent {
    @ContentChild(InputComponent, {
        descendants: false
    })
    public inputContent?:InputComponent;
}


<span class="input-wrapper">
    <label>{{inputContent?.label}}</label> <!-- Used for other stuff too -->
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</span>
```

And another wrapper-like, which is used to display multiple copies of an input (one for each language), which uses the wrapper above:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tw-input-localized',
  templateUrl: './input-localized.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-localized.component.scss']
})
export class InputLocalizedComponent {
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef<any>, {
        descendants: false,
        static: true
    })
    public inputTemplate?:TemplateRef<any>;
}


<tw-input-multi>
    <ng-container *ngIf="inputTemplate" [ngTemplateOutlet]="inputTemplate"></ng-container>
</tw-input-multi>
<tw-input-multi>
    <ng-container *ngIf="inputTemplate" [ngTemplateOutlet]="inputTemplate"></ng-container>
</tw-input-multi>
```

Used like this:

```
<tw-input-localized>
    <ng-template>
        <my-input></my-input>
    </ng-template>
</tw-input-localized>
```

The input gets rendered inside the inner wrapper but the `ContentChild` query doesn't get populated, because I found out that the template has to be there at compile time.

So I tried passing the input field to the wrapper as a parameter:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tw-input-multi',
  templateUrl: './input-multi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-multi.component.scss'],
  host:{
    'class': 'field'
  }
})
export class InputMultiComponent {
    @Input("input")
    public inputComponent?:InputComponent<AbstractControl>;

    @ContentChild(InputComponent, {
        descendants: false
    })
    public inputContent?:InputComponent;


    public get input():InputComponent<AbstractControl> | undefined{
        return this.inputComponent ?? this.inputContent;
    }
}


<span class="input-wrapper">
    <label>{{input?.label}}</label> <!-- Now using input getter instead -->
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</span>
```

So it should work both ways now, but when I use it inside my localized input I get an ExpressionChanged... exception because the input first gets added to the child and then the parent's binding gets updated.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tw-input-localized',
  templateUrl: './input-localized.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-localized.component.scss']
})
export class InputLocalizedComponent {
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef<any>, {
        descendants: false,
        static: true
    })
    public inputTemplate?:TemplateRef<any>;

    /**
     * Instances of the rendered input, one for each active locale
     */
    @ContentChildren(InputComponent)
    inputs!:QueryList<InputComponent>;
}


<tw-input-multi [input]="inputs[0]">
    <ng-container *ngIf="inputTemplate" [ngTemplateOutlet]="inputTemplate"></ng-container>
</tw-input-multi>
<tw-input-multi [input]="inputs[...]">
    <ng-container *ngIf="inputTemplate" [ngTemplateOutlet]="inputTemplate"></ng-container>
</tw-input-multi>
```

Any solution to this? I would prefer avoiding any service because these components should be very flexible to use and avoid external configuration.